# Difference between kernel of a matrix and kernel of a transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, definition

Does the word "kernel" carry different meanings in the contexts of matrices and transformations? Or are the definitions of the two in those two contexts intertwined in some way?

I know the kernel of a matrix to be it's null space. I haven't been taught about the kernel of a transformation yet, but I looked it up and it's a bunch of complicated stuff that doesn't make much sense (it's apparently every vector v that results in a transformation T outputting the zero vector?)

Are they just two different ideas?

Comment: See [Kernel of a Linear transformation](http://ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/203/matrixonvectors/kernelRange.htm) : The *kernel* of a linear transformation L is the set of all vectors v such that  $     L(v)  =  0$.

Answer (score 2):

The kernel of a matrix $A$ is the space of those vectors $v$ such that $A.v=0$. The kernel of a linear transformation $T$ is the space of those vectors $v$ such that $T(v)=0$. So, it is basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Every linear transformation from one **finite** dimensional space to another can be written as a matrix.  The only difference between "kernel of a linear transformation" and "kernel of a matrix" would be in the case of a linear transformation over infinite dimensional spaces which cannot be written as a matrix.  An example would be the "differentiation" operator on the space of all differentiable functions.  The kernel of that operator is the subspace of all constant functions.